# JSON Exception : String Cannot be convert to JSONObject in android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

I am fetching data from mysql database using JSON and set data in LIstview Item. My Java Code work fine. but i cannot get the value in listview. how can json value convert.

How can i Slove this.

```
      02-27 12:47:17.548: W/System.err(637): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPEHTMLPUBLIC"- of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
      02-27 12:47:17.557: W/System.err(637):    at  org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
      02-27 12:47:17.557: W/System.err(637):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
      02-27 12:47:17.557: W/System.err(637):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
      02-27 12:47:17.557: W/System.err(637):    at com.amplio.upshot.AddToOutlet.onCreate(AddToOutlet.java:42)
      02-27 12:47:17.557: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
      02-27 12:47:17.568: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
      02-27 12:47:17.568: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
      02-27 12:47:17.568: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
      02-27 12:47:17.568: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
      02-27 12:47:17.568: W/System.err(637):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
      02-27 12:47:17.568: W/System.err(637):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
      02-27 12:47:17.568: W/System.err(637):    at com.amplio.upshot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)
      02-27 12:47:17.568: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at           android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
      02-27 12:47:17.578: W/System.err(637):    at         com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
      02-27 12:47:17.588: W/System.err(637):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My JSON Result

```
{
"customer": [
    {
        "success": "1",
        "bus_name": "radeonpixels",
        "bus_id": "B108"
    },
    {
        "success": "1",
        "bus_name": "Om Sweets",
        "bus_id": "B109"
    }
]
}
```

AddToOutlet.java

```
 public class AddToOutlet extends Activity {
SessionManager session;
String success, cus_id, bus_id;
ArrayList<Item> item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addtooutlet);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    session.checkLoginback();

    item = new ArrayList<Item>();
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    // ID
    final String cus_id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cus_id", cus_id));
    String response = null;
    try {
        response = LoginHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                "http://10.0.2.2/android_api/add_to_outlet.php",
                postParameters);
        response = response.toString();
        response = response.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("customer");
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Item it = new Item();
            it.setBusname(json_data.getString("bus_name"));
            it.setBusid(json_data.getString("bus_id"));

            item.add(it);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(AddToOutlet.this,
            R.layout.addtooutlet_list_item, item);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Which one is line number 112 in MainActivity? `at com.amplio.upshot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)`

Comment: tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);

Comment: `<!DOCTYPEHTMLPUBLIC"` sure you get json response. it looks like a xml

Comment: And what happens when you navigate `http://10.0.2.2/android_api/add_to_outlet.php` with browser ? Are you sure it's only `{ "customer" : ...`

Comment: @Zefnus yes I got this.

Comment: @Raghunandan what i do to convert json object in string

Comment: @Amardeep try `String jsonstring = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())`

Comment: @Raghunandan response = response.toString();
        response = response.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); i am using this

Answer (score 1):

First of all use appropriate contents and standard code.

Write basic network posting operation like:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postStuff = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android_api/add_to_outlet.php");
```

Then execute the client with post and save this in a **HttpResponse** variable not in a simple string.

What you did.. `String response = null;`

But you have to do like:

```
 HttpResponse response = client.execute(postStuff);
```

Now you can get the server return through `response.getEntity().getContent()` Or you also can check its status like `response.getStatusLine.getStatusCode()`.

Problem:

```
    response = response.toString();
    response = response.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Here you delete all white spaces from the string ,so its difficult to recognize the JsonObject. And I think this made problem to parse.

If the return type is perfect then your code is something like:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postStuff = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android_api/add_to_outlet.php");
HttpResponse response = null;
try{
response = client.execute(postStuff);
Bufferedreader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());

String mReturnDta = "";
while((data = reader.readLine()) != null){
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(mReturnDta);
//Now fetch the jsonarray and do whatever you want...
}    
}catch(...)
```